# GetPositionStream not being updated while application is in background through Isolate

Tags: flutter

getPositionStream not being updated while application is in background how we can get update latitude and longitude while app in inactive mode in flutter.

I'm trying to fetch background update location using position stream with Isolate background task but not getting update latitude and longitude while app in background.

Comment: I think your only option is to get woken up when you cross a geofence boundary.  I don't think you'll be able to poll when in background.  I could be wrong, and hopefully someone will post a more accurate answer. :)